# Ruby on Rails vs Tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tomcat, warbler

I am trying to run my rails app on tomcat.

First, I installed warbler through gems and everything's ok!
Basically, i added on my gem file: "gem 'warbler'" and then, "bundle install". Ok.

After, I went to localhost:8083 (tomcat) >> MANAGER APP >> WAR file to deploy and selected the war file generated by "warbler". Tomcat said **OK**.

When I access the page localhost:8083/TicketProject, here is the problem.

Tomcat say me that:

```
Internal Server Error (500)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    localhost:8083/TicketProject/

You have requested: pg >= 0 The bundle currently has pg locked at 0.17.1. Try running `bundle update pg` 
from C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:357:in `resolve' 
from C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:164:in `start' 
from C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:129:in `resolve' 
from C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:193:in `resolve' 
from C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs' 
from C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for' 
from C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs' from C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs' 
from C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup' 
from C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:121:in `setup' from C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `(root)' 
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require' from /C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.16.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1:in `(root)' 
from /C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.16.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require' 
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require' from C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/config/boot.rb:4:in `(root)' 
from /C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.16.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1:in `(root)' 
from /C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-stdlib-complete-1.7.16.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/TicketProject/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.16.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment3.rb:23:in `load_environment'
```

**Someone can help me?
Thanks in advance!!**

Comment: I don't know why, but I can't understand anything of this. --'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget Tomcat and use Passenger with Linux Server.. works perfectly!

Comment: Note Marcelo's solution is not free.